# change NSMenuItem title with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I want to change the title of the MenuItem after the login process has been completed successfully and once the user logs off.

But if I log in and check the title of the menu item, it has not changed. I have even tried to hide it, with no success.

This is my code

```
var mainMenu:NSMenu
var LoginButton:NSMenuItem
mainMenu=NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu!
LoginButton=mainMenu.itemWithTitle("Login")!
LoginButton.title="LogOff"
LoginButton.hidden=true
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

Bind the `Title` parameter of the menu item in Interface Builder / Bindings Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd>) to a property with `dynamic` attribute in `AppDelegate`.

For example declare in `AppDelegate`

```
@objc dynamic var logonTitle = "Login"
```

and bind the `Title` parameter of the menu item to `AppDelegate` > Model Key Path `logonTitle`

Now whenever you change the value of `logonTitle` the title changes accordingly.

No further references, outlets etc. needed.

PS: Please name your variables consistently starting with a lowercase letter as recommended in the Guidelines.